# Why query inside query is slower than 2 queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have query like this

```
UPDATE Table2 
   SET status = 2  
   WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM Table1 WHERE date > 0)
```

It took like 10 seconds to execute
i break into two queries using php

```
q1 ="SELECT user_id FROM Table1 WHERE date > 0"
$q1_res=sql->execq($q1);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($q1_res); $i++) {
    foreach ($q1_res[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "user_id") {
            $q1_res_ids .= $value . ",";
        }
    }
}

$q2 ="UPDATE Table2 
       SET status = 2  
       WHERE user_id IN". $q1_res_ids
$sql->execq($q2);
```

this took less than 1 second to execute i would think its faster to use MYSQL?

Comment: Hint: [`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: [It might also be worth worrying about things like "if I do two separate queries, what happens if someone else modifies the data between my two queries?". Maybe not in this case, but in general]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first performed the second query, and shortly thereafter your PHP script, it is likely that the result of the select query was already cached by the [Mysql Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html), since the queries are identical. That would explain the difference in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in this example is a correlated query. That is, it runs the outer query once for EVERY row of the inner query. So if you have 200 users with date > 0, you will be running 400 queries.

The PHP version runs the subquery only once and then runs a single query to update all found rows.